# How to dislike an item in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

here is my code
my like code is working but, dislike is not working,please give me a solution
this is my index.html.erb

`<% if !current_or_null_user.liked? product %>
                        <span class="fav_icon"><%= link_to '', likes_create_path(:id => product.id), class: 'fav_icon', :title => "Like", method: :post %></span>
                    <% else %>
                <span class="unfav_icon"><%= link_to '', like_path(:id => product.id), class: 'unfav_icon', :title => "Dislike", method: :delete %>`

my likescontoller

`class LikesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        if user_signed_in?

            Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, product_id: params[:id]).first_or_create
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'You liked the product!'
        else
            redirect_to :back, alert: 'You need to be logged in to like product!'
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @like = Like.find(params[:id])
        @like.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'You unliked the item.' }
        end
    end
end`

model like.rb

`class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end`

model user.rb

`has_many :likes
 has_many :liked_products, through: :likes, source: :product
  def liked? product
    liked_products.include? product
  end`

model product.rb

`has_many :likes`

Comment: Use four spaces to indent your code, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
def destroy
  @like = Like.find(params[:id])
  @like.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'You unliked the item.' }
  end
end
```

to this

```
def destroy
  if user_signed_in?
    @like = Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, product_id: params[:id]).first
    if @like.present?
      @like.destroy
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You unliked item.'
    else
      redirect_to :back, alert: 'You have no liked item.'
    end
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'You need to be logged in to like product!'
  end
end
```

Comment: i would suggest to add before_filter/before_action depending upon the rails version which checks for user_signed_in? that way your action would be cleaner

Comment: sorry i just said that because i see this check `if user_signed_in?` in create and delete(which i added). if you have already added that is best and  you don't need explicit check.